# Missing Cursor after standby

Tags: release-freya, mouse, drivers

I am having an issue where since doing some recent updates, not sure which, when I come back after a while and my laptop comes back from standby I can no longer see my cursor. It is still there and I can see when i move it that its moving around its just invisible.

I have a 2013 Macbook Air running latest Elementry install.

Any tips to fix this permanently?

Cheers
C

Answer (score 1):

This is the same with my problem, my laptop is Dell Vostro 1440, when i press WIN + L (lock the computer), after that when i login the cursor will disappear.
I look for this problem and this is the way to fix it but when i logout and login again, i will have the missing cursor again:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active true
```

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1568604

I think this bug'll be fixed in loki RC1

A quicker workaround is ctrl+alt+f1 and ctrl+alt+f7

Answer (score 0):

none of the f1 and f7 workarounds worked for me. Freya on a chromebook. If you are like me, try opening a you tube video any one will do and move the mouse around a bit. Then it will appear.